# Apache Servicemix windows - Works in Localhost but not with the public IP address

Tags: windows, apache, apache-servicemix

I have a apache servicemix instance running in AWS window instance. The security groups are intact, so you dont have to doubt that

When I run the servicemix instance, I can access it inside the machine with `localhost:8181` but when the access it outside as `x.x.x.x:8181` am  getting connection refused.

Where do I add the configuration to expose it to IP address.

The surprising thing is, it works out of the box in a Linux instance without needing to change any configuration. Only windows instance is creating problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Found the problem. If you are using a Windows instance in AWS , adding security group alone will not be enough. Log in to the instance, got to Windows firewall and add a new Rule to allow the required port. Should work then

Surprising that its not documented anywhere.

This solution is not just for servicemix , but for everything.